# If condition + concatenation with JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I've a JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "error_code": 603,
    "error_desc": "Some ads error occurs: URL needed.",
    "taskId": 630
  },
  {
    "id": 36154,
    "taskId": 631
  }
]
```

If `id` equals 0, then `error_code` and `error_desc` keys appears. I want to get this result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "taskStatus": "ERROR",
    "errorMessage": "603|Some ads error occurs: URL needed.",
    "taskId": 630
  },
  {
    "id": 36154,
    "taskStatus": "SUCCESS",
    "errorMessage": null,
    "taskId": 631
  }
]
```

`taskStatus` should be set to `ERROR` if `id = 0` and `SUCCESS` if id != 0. `errorMessage` is `error_code` + `|` + `error_desc` and is null if id != 0.

Is it possible to do with JOLT? It seems like an `if-else` condition, which I didnt work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply conditional within the **shift**, while concatenation within the **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": {
          "@": "[&2].&", // replicate "id" itself
          "0": { // if "id" = 0
            "#ERROR": "[&3].taskStatus",
            "@2,error_code|@2,error_desc": "[&3].errorMessage"
            // combine the error related attributes within a common array
          },
          "*": { // if "id" != 0
            "#SUCCESS": "[&3].taskStatus",
            "@": "[&3].errorMessage"
          }
        },
        "taskId": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate the components of the "errorMessage" array
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "err*": "=join('|',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]